# Django registration url redirection

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls, django-registration

I am using `Django==1.8` and `django-registration-redux` for registration. When I try to login with my superuser and password, it is automatically redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/`. Is there any way I can control where my `url` will redirect once the user logged in? You can see the below image: [image]

Suppose I want to redirect to `/home/` once the user logged in, then how will i do that? Please help!!

`Login.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p>{% trans "Forgot password" %}? <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "Not member" %}? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can customize this by putting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py file.

So in this case you can do it like...

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /home/
```

Comment: I will put LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /home/ in settings.py?